# website trying to scroll where there isnt anything

Tags: html, css

my website has a scroll bar that goes quite far over to the right and one that goes down. nothing is displayed in these areas so the scroll bar is unecesary! if anything it could fit all on one page. these creates a lot of white space around my page.

how can i stop this from happening?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Paytone+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<title>Louis Moore | Creating The Future  </title>
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="ie.css" >
<![endif]-->

</head>
<style>
.box {
background-color: #F1F2F2;
border: 1.5px #D1D3D4 solid;
position: relative;
top: 100px;
height:450px;
width:100%;
}
.image1 {
position: relative;
top:-100px;
left: 390px;
}
body{
font-family: 'Paytone One', sans-serif;
font-size: 30px;
}
h1 {
font-family: 'Paytone One', sans-serif;
font-size: 40px;
position: relative;
top:-250px;
left: 370px;
}
h2 {
font-family: 'Paytone One', sans-serif;
font-size: 30px;
position: relative;
top:-300px;
left: 480px;
color: #FC3B3B;
}
h3 {
font-family: 'Paytone One', sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
position: relative;
top:-290px;
left: 390px;
}
.image2 {
position: relative;
top:-300px;
left: 590px;
}
.box1 {
width: 100%;
height: 5px;
background-color:  #FC3B3B;
position: relative;
top:100px;
left: 0px;
}
p {
position: relative;
top:150px;
left: 100px;
font-size: 15px;
font-family: arial;
color: #585858;
}
</style>


<body>
<div class="box">
<img src="louis.png" class="image1" alt="." width="400px" height="400px">
<h1> WELCOME TO MY PAGE</h1> 
<h2>COMING SOON... </h2>
<h3>BUT FOR NOW FOLLOW ME ON TWITTER</h3>
<a href="http://twitter.com/louismoore18"><img src="twitter.png" class="image2" border="0" alt="."></a>
</div>
<div class="box1">

</div>
<p>louismoore.net © All rights reserved 2012</p>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: this is how it should look like
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an artifact of the `relative` positioning and setting a `left` value.

Remove it, and the extra space goes away.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eB9sA/)

#### EDIT

You do not need any relative positioning. The design you are trying to accomplish can be created much more simply with `text-align: center`.

HTML

```
<div>
  <img src="//placehold.it/200x200">
  <h1>Welcome to my page</h1>
  <h2>Coming Soon...</h2>
  <h3>But for now follow me on Twitter</h3>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Paytone+One);

div {
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: 'Paytone One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
}

h1 { 
    font-size: 2em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: red;
}

img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    }​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jG4Hb/)

Comment: but if i remove the left value then the elements will not be in the desired area

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What sort of design are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: i have edited my post to how i want it to look. it does look like that but with added space around it. you can view it here [HERE](http://louismoore.net)

Comment: I updated my answer. In my opinion, relative positioning is the wrong way to accomplish this design. Learn from my example and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: thanks your code looks like it will be much more effective for my design. one question, how would i raise h2 so it was a little closer to h1

Comment: Adjust the line-height, e.g. `h2 {line-height: 1em;}`

Comment: thank you. and how will i move h1 closer to img1? and move img2 closer to h3